# Table in IE7 with 100% width overflowing containing div

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, internet-explorer-7

I have a table of results inside an area div. Because I am using a fluid layout, the area div doesn't have a  set width. The width of the table is set to 100%, but in IE7 it overflows beyond the containing div. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="area">
    <table id="results">
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#results{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! I needed to set white-space:normal for all the TDs and THs within the table.

Comment: Awesome, I was having this same issue with IE on a page that I maintain. Don't forget to Accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to give `zoom: 1` to the parent `<div>` of table `#area { zoom: 1 }`